# React-native renders my object every time I got into the page

Tags: react-native, render, lifecycle

I pass an object to a child component and every time i got into the page, it re-renders.

I tried to overwrite my array with an empty one, in the componentWillUnmount method, but it doesn't work.

```
let array = new Array<myType>
export default class Parent extends Component{

   componentDidMount():void {
      array.name = 'John'
      array.lastName = 'Smith'
   }

   render(){
     return(
        <View>
           <ChildComponent data={array}/>
        </View>
     )
   }  
}

_______________________Child

interface myProps{
   data: Array<myType>
}

export default class ChildComponent extends Component<myProps>{
   state={
     childData = this.props.data
   }   

   componentWillUnmount(): any {
        this.unMountState();
    }

    unMountState = () => {
        this.setState({childData: new Array<myType>()})
    };

   render(){
     return(
        <View>
           {this.state.childData.map((item, key) => (
                    <Text>{item.name} {item.lastName}</Text>

                ))}
        </View>
     )
   }  
}
```

Every time I go back and back inside the parent page, it re-renders the array! 
So I have an output like:
John Smith
John Smith
John Smith
.
.
.

Comment: What do you mean it's re-rendering? What should happen? If data is passed through props, data will be rendered when the component re-renders

Comment: The parent is a page in which I get with a navigation. Every time I go in that page it doubles my datas. It's like if it doesn't unmount the component. It should show me the datas (name and lastname) just once

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an object instead of `Array`, in this way your code would be like this and you don't need the `componentWillUnmount` anymore.

```
let dataObj = {};

export default class Parent extends Component {
  componentDidMount(): void {
    dataObj.name = 'John';
    dataObj.lastName = 'Smith';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ChildComponent data={dataObj} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

//------------------- Child Component

export default class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      childData: this.props.data,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { childData } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {childData.name} {childData.lastName}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I need to use an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, if you want to display a list of items in `react-native` then always use `Flatlist` it gives lot of in built benefits over map.

Replace your map with a Flatlist as follows,

```
<FlatList
   data={this.props.data}
   extraData={this.state}
   keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
   renderItem={this._renderItem}
 />

 _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id

_renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
  );
```

keyExtractor is very important which will identify each element uniquely.

Using Flatlist your issue will be solved.

Comment: But at the second time I get into the page, there's a warning: Encountered two children with the same key '0'.

Comment: @palnic You to implement keyExtractor so that it will identify each element uniquely..